# IBInspectable property set at design time not keeping value

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

We are in the process of implementing IBInspectable into a large app in hopes of allowing some settings to be set in Interface Builder to reduce the amount of code in our views. I don't have much experience with IBInspectable/IBDesignable and am looking for some answers and/or clarification on what I'm doing wrong.

I have declared a property in a UITableViewCell subclass as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBInspectable UIColor* backgroundColor;
```

When declaring the property like this, I get an option to set that color in Interface Builder > Attributes Inspector, which is to be expected. However when I set the color, the value for `_backgroundColor` is nil at runtime.

```
[_labelLoginBackground setBackgroundColor:_backgroundColor];
```

Could someone clarify what might be going here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, which already contains a property named "backgroundColor". Do 1 of the following:

1. Rename your own "backgroundColor" property to "loginBackgroundColor" and start debugging from there.

**OR**

2. Do not create a redundant property. Set the background color using the selection widget that is already present in Interface Builder before you ever add IBInspectable.

[image]